# How To set animation time to infinity using css

Tags: html, css, angular, animation, marquee

I want to scroll my whole content of the dom from bottom to top till the content is rendered completely but I faced the problem of timing of animation as it rendered the content till 10s and start again from the top which is not my usecase.

```css
/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
  height:300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;    
}

.marquee:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { margin-top: 150%; }
  100% { margin-top: -150% }
}

/* Make it pretty */
.microsoft {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  font: 16px 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

/* ::before was :before before ::before was ::before - kthx */
.microsoft:before, .microsoft::before {
  z-index: 2;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em; left: -1em;
  width: .5em; height: .5em;
  box-shadow: 1.0em 1.25em 0 #F65314,
          1.6em 1.25em 0 #7CBB00,
          1.0em 1.85em 0 #00A1F1,
          1.6em 1.85em 0 #FFBB00;
}



/* Style the links */
.vanity {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  font: .75em 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.vanity a, .microsoft a {
  color: #1570A6;
  transition: color .5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vanity a:hover, .microsoft a:hover {
  color: #F65314;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;">

  <p class="microsoft marquee">
    <ul>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
      <li>asdfa</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

As mentioned the animation time -s 10s so it runs for only 10seconds so please provide me any way to execute it till my whole Dom rendered. i.e set to no limit. It's this line in particular:

```
animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
```

Comment: Please add the relevant html aswell and make it a working code snippet

Comment: @SuperDJ I've attached the html code as well and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The HTML markup is invalid. A `ul` should not be in a `p`

Comment: the infinite keyword you provided on the animation only helps you to play the existing animation over and over . It didn't make the animation to play until  the bottom of the page

Comment: animation duration specifies the length of time an animation should take to complete one cycle. This can be specified in `seconds or milliseconds`. Default value is 0, which means that no animation will occur

Comment: @newton_cr7 so what can i do to run it until the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Suryan what can do so that my content will rendered completely until the bottom of the page.

Comment: Solution using JQuery aur Angular 2 or higher are highly acceptable.

Comment: @Nitin let me ask something. are you looking for autoscroll until the bottom is reached??

Comment: @newton_cr7  Yes i was but my problem is solved now thanks.